# How do you collect data from all your threads in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads, collect

So I made a `class` that extends `Thread` class and I have a main class that calls `start()`.
I have created 1000 threads to run my program in this way:

```
int ThreadNum = 1000;
for(int i=0; i<ThreadNum; i++){
   Thread_Class function = new Thread_Class();// The Thread_Class is the one that extends the Thread class.
function.start();                    }
```

does this make 1000 of threads? And how do I collect the data backs from all the threads?

Thank you so much!! I all appreciate!

Comment: yes you are creating `1000` threads and what data you want to collect back?

Comment: I let each Thread run a function that will produce a number as a double type, and I want to collect them all from all these 1000 Threads and be able to use the collected data and do something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way of constructing Threads in your question is just fine, but you are spinning a new `Thread` for every iteration in the loop which is a very bad idea.

Constructing a new Thread is a costly affair you must refrain from. To alleviate this problem, `ThreadPool` is made which contains `Thread`s.

You have created `Thread`s successfully, but it wont return a value. Note that start method is responsible for only starting the thread. You can either wait/interrupt the spawned thread while it is working. There is no way for returning an Object.

From the docs of `Runnable`,

> A Runnable, however, does not return a result and cannot throw a
>   checked exception.

And yeah, `class Thread implements Runnable`. You have created objects of classes **extending** `Thread`. So the behaviour is same for you.

Alternate would be to go ahead with `Callable` as answered by @Ravindra.

From the docs of `Callable`

> A task that returns a result and may throw an exception.

which is exactly what you need.

PS: Also, note that `future.get()` is a blocking call. And is always recommended to use it with timeouts.

Comment: There's no such thing that states `future.get` should always be called with timeouts. If there's any please show it in the documentation.